# Ошибка "init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'command_prefix'" Discord bot

Tags: python, бот, discord

Я создаю бота и столкнуться с проблемой:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bot.py", line 4, in client = commands.Bot( commands_prefix = '$') 
TypeError: init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'command_prefix'
```

---

Вот мой код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot( commands_prefix = '$' )

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print('Bot')

@client.commands ( pass_context = True)

async def hello( ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello')

token = open ('token.txt', 'r').readline()

client.run (token)
```

Answer (score 3):

исходя из [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=command_prefix):

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    pass

# or:

@commands.command()
async def test(ctx):
    pass

bot.add_command(test)
```

`bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')`

у Вас же: `commands.Bot( command`**s**`_prefix = '$' )`